# Maven compiler plugin v3.8.1 only compiling 3 out of 198 classes

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

Tried to compile a maven project that up until now has always worked, but today when compiling it only compiled a small subset of classes.

I've tried changing the build settings but since the files are being fed to the input I can't understand why it's not being compiled.

The maven-status created and input files look like this:

input:

```
/home/nuno/IdeaProjects/MineWars/core/src/main/java/net/havocmc/gamemodes/minewars/core/vehicles/types/air/TieInterceptor.java
    /home/nuno/IdeaProjects/MineWars/core/src/main/java/net/havocmc/gamemodes/minewars/core/ability/animations/ForceChokeAnim.java
    /home/nuno/IdeaProjects/MineWars/core/src/main/java/net/havocmc/gamemodes/minewars/core/util/Skin.java
    /home/nuno/IdeaProjects/MineWars/core/src/main/java/net/havocmc/gamemodes/minewars/core/vehicles/listeners/bukkit/EntityListener.java
...
```

created:

```
net/havocmc/gamemodes/minewars/core/mobs/listener/PlayerShootListener.class
net/havocmc/gamemodes/minewars/core/mobs/EntityManager.class
net/havocmc/gamemodes/minewars/core/mobs/configs/MobConfigManager.class
```

The maven compile log is:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for net.havocmc.gamemodes.minewars:core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.spigotmc:spigot-1.12:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/../library/spigot-1.12.2.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 36, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for net.havocmc:Core:jar is either LATEST or RELEASE (both of them are being deprecated) @ net.havocmc.gamemodes.minewars:MineWars:1.0-SNAPSHOT, /home/nuno/IdeaProjects/MineWars/pom.xml, line 106, column 22
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------< net.havocmc.gamemodes.minewars:core >-----------------
[INFO] Building core 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for net.havocmc.util.currency:GameModeUtils:jar:1.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for net.havocmc.weapons:Weapons:jar:1.5 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for net.havocmc:Utilities:jar:1.5 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for net.havocmc:Core:jar:1.4 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for net.havocmc:Loot:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ core ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ core ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 198 source files to /home/nuno/IdeaProjects/MineWars/core/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.297 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-08-13T19:06:05+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The project is structured like so:

- Minewars

  - core
  - game

The minewars pom is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.havocmc.gamemodes.minewars</groupId>
    <artifactId>MineWars</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>core</module>
        <module>duels</module>
        <module>game</module>
    </modules>

    <name>MineWars</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <main.basedir>${project.basedir}</main.basedir>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>clean compile package install</defaultGoal>
        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</sourceDirectory>
        <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                            <minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org.spigotmc:spigot</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spigot-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>

        <!-- For glowing (spectral effect) -->
        <repository>
            <id>inventive-repo</id>
            <url>https://repo.inventivetalent.org/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>

        <!--Citizens-->
        <repository>
            <id>citizens-npcs</id>
            <url>http://repo.citizensnpcs.co/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- This adds the Spigot API artifact to the build -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.havocmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>Core</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.havocmc.weapons</groupId>
            <artifactId>Weapons</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.havocmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>Loot</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Citizens-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.citizensnpcs</groupId>
            <artifactId>citizensapi</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.18-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.inventivetalent</groupId>
            <artifactId>glowapi</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>craftbukkit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.inventivetalent.packetlistener</groupId>
                    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>tmd-new-repo</id>
            <url>sftp://192.99.55.236/var/www/html/repos</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

the core pom is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>MineWars</artifactId>
        <groupId>net.havocmc.gamemodes.minewars</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>core</artifactId>

    <repositories>
        <!-- Protocol Lib -->
        <repository>
            <id>dmulloy2-repo</id>
            <url>http://repo.dmulloy2.net/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>md_5-public</id>
            <url>http://repo.md-5.net/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- For NMS access -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-1.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/../library/spigot-1.12.2.jar</systemPath>
            <scope>system</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.havocmc.util.currency</groupId>
            <artifactId>GameModeUtils</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.comphenix.protocol</groupId>
            <artifactId>ProtocolLib-API</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>LibsDisguises</groupId>
            <artifactId>LibsDisguises</artifactId>
            <version>9.9.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Weapons-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.havocmc.weapons</groupId>
            <artifactId>Weapons</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>*</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!--Utils-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.havocmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>Utilities</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>*</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>clean compile package install</defaultGoal>
        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</sourceDirectory>
        <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, was a problem with an import that might have been causing issues? I don't really know why, just that it worked when I removed it.